# What exactly are relativistic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Is magnetic field relativistic? Is electric field relativistic? How do you imagine something causing an actual physical difference to be purely dependent on the choice of a reference frame?

Comment: The fact the the Lorentz force is described by a $B$ field when the charge moves, resp., by an $E$ field when it is at rest is the very reason that led Einstein to develop SRT. Even the title of his seminal paper stresses that fact: [On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies](https://scirp.org/reference/referencespapers.aspx?referenceid=2127745).

Comment: The answer to the question "What exactly are relativistic [Electromagnetic] fields?" is that in relativity the field is described by the [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Relationship_with_the_classical_fields) $F_{\mu\nu}$ whose components are neither purely electric, nor purely magnetic. That depends on the reference frame. There are plenty of PSE posts on this plus plenty of literature in the internet and in print.